# Postgres - UPDATE table using JOINS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `products`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | purchase_date   | product  | product_info_join_table_id | shipment_status_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | '2017-01-01'    | computer | 23                         | null
2  | '2018-01-01'    | printer  | 45                         | null
3  | '2019-01-01'    | keyboard | 34                         | null
```

There is a `product_info_join` table that links the `products` table to other tables, such as `country_to_ship` table:

`product_info_join`:

```
------------------------------
id  | destination_id   
------------------------------
23  | 11                     
45  | 11                     
34  | 12
```

`country_to_ship`:

```
--------------------
id  | destination   
--------------------
11  | United States                     
12  | Mexico
```

I need to figure out what the shipment status of each item is (which is currently `null`). To do so, I need to look up the `shipment_status` table.

`shipment_status`

```
----------------------------
id  | country       | status
----------------------------
1   | United States | ship                     
2   | Mexico        | hold
```

So when I go to `UPDATE` the `products` table, it should look like this (notice the updated `shipment_status_id` column):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | purchase_date   | product  | product_info_join_table_id | shipment_status_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | '2017-01-01'    | computer | 23                         | 1
2  | '2018-01-01'    | printer  | 45                         | 1
3  | '2019-01-01'    | keyboard | 34                         | 2
```

So I am trying to `UPDATE` the `products` table by joining it with the `product_info_join` and `country_to_ship` to get the `destination` column. I then want to use the `desitnation` column to look up the `shipment_status` table to fill the `shipment_status_id` column (which indicates whether or not to ship the item).

```
WITH cte_shipment_status AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM shipment_status
    WHERE country IN ('United States', 'Mexico')
)
UPDATE products
SET shipment_status_id = (SELECT id FROM cte_shipment_status WHERE country = destination)
    LEFT JOIN product_info_join ON products.product_info_join_table_id = product_info_join.id
    LEFT JOIN country_to_ship ON product_info_join.destination_id = country_to_ship.id;
```

This doesn't work because you can't use `LEFT JOIN` as I have. I know you are supposed to use a `FROM` clause to do `JOIN`'s with `UPDATE`, but I don't know how I can use `FROM` when I am trying to join two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the logic like this:

```
update products p
    set shipment_status_id = ss.id
    from product_info_join pij join
         country_to_ship cs
         on pij.destination_id = cs.id join
         shipment_status ss
         on ss.country = cs.destination
    where pij.id = p.product_info_join_table_id and
          cs.country in ('United States', 'Mexico');
```

This really assumes that there is only match in the underlying tables.